# supersolution of Laplace operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem is that I want to find a solution $u$ s.t.
$\Delta u>0, u=0$  on $\partial\Omega$,where $\Omega$ is the domain $[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @John I have no clue about it since I just learn Laplace equation

Comment: You can first try some polynomials.

Comment: @John any hint for me? Thanks

Comment: You can first think of a function $f$ with one variable such that $f''>0, f<0, $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and consider $u(x, y) = -f(x)f(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by John in a comment:

Take $u(x, y) = -f(x)f(y)$ where   $f$ is a function of one variable such that $f''>0$, $f<0$, $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.

Indeed, $\Delta u= -f''(x)f(y) -f(x)f''(y)>0$ for such a function.